# Limit 6 posts per post type

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Im trying to determine the best way to approach this problem. I have created a plugin that will call on three post types( posts, events, news ) so in my plugin I use a single query to call them like so

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => array( 'post', 'tribe_events', 'news_update' ),
'posts_per_page' => 6
);

$news = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What I need to do is grab the latest 6 posts of each post type to use with jQuery tabs. Using the `posts_per_page` arg limits the whole query which is not what I want. So there will be four tabs.

`All | News | Blog | Events`

Each tab should only show 6 posts.

What are some options that I have to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way is to run `wp_query` three times for each post type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would put them into three separate queries and use transients to avoid heavy load. I'm curious as to whether there's a custom SQL query to achieve this and I'd love for someone else to give me more info on that if possible.

My solution would be:

```
if ( ! ( $news = get_transient( 'wpse_tab_posts_news' ) ) ) { 
    $news = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
    ) );

    set_transient( 'wpse_tab_posts_news', $news, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
}
```

Repeat this for the three queries. One for news, one for tribe_events, and one for news_update.

You will then have three arrays of posts that will be stored for a day at a time.

I'd encourage you to look into the transients API and specifically how to delete transients early so they update when you publish a new post etc.

You could then merge these arrays for use in your all tab.

Further reading: http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did consider using three separate queries but did not think about using the transient api, nice touch. I will look into the API.